# JavaScript change fontsize not working everywhere

Tags: javascript, html

I have that code:

```
function change_npsize()
{
   document.getElementById("np_drag").style.fontSize = document.getElementsByName("npsize").item(0).value;
};


<input type="text" name="npsize" size="2" maxlength="2" value="<?=$userinfo->npsize; ?>" onchange="change_npsize()" />

<div id="drag-container" style="position:relative;font-family:<?=$userinfo->font?>;">
    <div id="np_drag" style="color:<?=$userinfo->npcolor?>; font-size:<?=$userinfo->npsize?>px;" class="draggable np_drag" style="position:absolute;left:80px;">
     .::[ NowPlaying SIGnature ]::.
     </div>
</div>
```

That code is working only in IE. I tried Firefox and Google Chrome.

Comment: is there any reason you don't you also give the text input an id?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper usage of [`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName) (at least in Firefox) is:

```
getElementsByName("npsize")[0];
```

The following works (at least in Chrome):

```
document.getElementById("np_drag").style.fontSize = document.getElementsByName("npsize")[0].value + "px";
```

Note the `+ "px"` at the end; you can’t just set it to a numeric value, you need to include the appropriate unit in the value.

Comment: Not working. And with that code it's not working and in IE. 
I realized something : even if I replace document.getElementsByName("npsize").item(0).value with simple integer, its not working again. So problem is somewhere in document.getElementById("np_drag").style.fontSize

Comment: Put `alert("test");` in the beginning of the `change_npsize()` function and see if it pops up when expected.

Comment: @Andrew : alert works fine in all browsers. But no fontSize change.

Comment: Did you replace it with a number or something like `"12px"`? Try the latter if you didn't.

Comment: @Andrew: document.getElementById("np_drag").style.Size = '20px';
Not working even in IE. Works only if its without '' and px and just in IE.

Comment: It should be `document.getElementById("np_drag").style.fontSize` like you had originally.

Comment: Yeah. The problem was missing px... :) Sometimes I really hate these little things that mess up everything. Sorry for taking your time. :) Now its:

`document.getElementById("np_drag").style.fontSize = document.getElementById("npsize").value + "px";`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this working code :

your HTML :

```
<input type="text" name="npsize" size="10" maxlength="2" value="small"/><br/><hr/>
<div id="np_drag">font</div>
```

your JavaScript :

```
document.getElementById("np_drag").style.fontSize = document.getElementsByName("npsize")[0].value;
```

See this working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/saranghdave/Zg7Am/).

Also, please correct me if I am wrong.

**EDIT :** I have changed the fiddle with your correctness at other answer.

Comment: Change the value property with "small","xx-large","medium" etc.

Comment: Please, post your code *here*. jsfiddle does not guarantee a permanent store of your code, so in the future that link may break

Comment: Thanks for Information Yi. I don't know this issue. So, lemme update.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is not .fontsize ....

it might be .size

Comment: @AndrewMarshall [Please don't use W3Schools](http://w3fools.com/) as a reference source. [This MDC page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSS) contains a pretty good list which should do.

Comment: @Yi I like that site (w3fools that is, not schools). I don't like it either but it has the unfortunate side effect of often being the top hit on google when looking for a quick reference :\